# Assign permission for pages using Code first in asp.net MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Here I have created a Model Structure in asp.net mvc:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int UserId {  get;  set;  }
    public string UserName  {  get;   set;  }
    public string Password   {    get; set;    }
    public List<Permission> Permissions {   get;   set;  }
    public string FirstName {  get;  set;  }
    public string LastName {  get;   set;  }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionID {   get;  set;   }
    public bool IsPermit   {  get;  set;  }
    public string Name  {  get;  set;  }
}
```

and setting some default values in the list and while I am adding the user in the list I assign the permission for pages to that user through the UI (by checking permission checkboxes), so that user can access only the assigned pages:

```
public static class Repository
{
    public static List<UserModel> GetUsers()
    {
        List<UserModel> listUsers = new List<UserModel>
        {
            new UserModel
            {
                UserId = 1,
                UserName = "abc",
                Password = "abc",
                Permissions = new List<Permission>
                {
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 1,
                        IsPermit = true,
                        Name = "Page1"
                    },
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 2,
                        IsPermit = false,
                        Name = "Page2"
                    },
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 3,
                        IsPermit = false,
                        Name = "Page3"
                    },
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 4,
                        IsPermit = false,
                        Name = "Page4"
                    }
                },
                FirstName = "Rohit",
                LastName = "Sharma"
            },

            new UserModel
            {
                UserId = 2,
                UserName = "xyz",
                Password = "xyz",
                Permissions = new List<Permission>
                {
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 1,
                        IsPermit = false,
                        Name = "Page1"
                    },
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 2,
                        IsPermit = true,
                        Name = "Page2"
                    },
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 3,
                        IsPermit = true,
                        Name = "Page3"
                    },
                    new Permission
                    {
                        PermissionID = 4,
                        IsPermit = true,
                        Name = "Page4"
                    }
                },
                FirstName = "Rahul",
                LastName = "Sharma"
            }
        };

        return listUsers;
    }
}
```

Now I want to do the same by using code first approach of database with the help of DbContext class. I have a static list of page permission in a database table (Id =1, Name=Page1; Id =2, Name=Page2; Id =3, Name=Page3; Id =4, Name=Page4).

I am confused while creating model structure for database. Please guide me how to create model structure and mapping of structure with the tables.

I have a table (Permission) in my database with default rows.

```
ID Name

1 Page1

2 Page2

3 Page3

4 Page4
```

Now, when I adding user I assigning permission to that user through static checkboxes (Page1, Page2, Page3 and Page4). That’s why I created static table in a database that contains list of pages. My User table is initially blank.

```
User

Id            int             NotNull

UserName      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull

Password      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull

FirstName     nvarchar(100)   AllowNull

LastName      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
```

Comment: by using above structure can you retrieve data from "Permission" table ? I feel you cannot.B'cos your model and table properties are totally different ???.What are the codes you have written so far for get permission data from database.Put that code also.And your view code also need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned structure when you're using code first.You have to maintain conventions when you're using code first (But can be changed when you're using Fluent API).

**Model Classes**

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {  get;  set;  }
    public string UserName  {  get;   set;  }
    public string Password   {    get; set;    }
    public string FirstName {  get;  set;  }
    public string LastName {  get;   set;  }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions {   get;   set;  }

}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id {   get;  set;   }
    public bool IsPermit   {  get;  set;  }
    public string Name  {  get;  set;  }

    public virtual User {   get;   set;  }

}
```

**Tables** (This will auto generate.But If you want you can create manually also)

```
Users

Id            int             NotNull
UserName      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
Password      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
FirstName     nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
LastName      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull


Permissions

Id            int             NotNull
IsPermit      bit             AllowNull
Name          nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
User_Id       int             NotNull
```

**DbContext Derived Class**

```
public class UserEntities : DbContext
    {
       public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
    }
```

Fore more information check [**Code-First Development with Entity Framework**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I already have a static list of permission in a database table (Permission). In this case permissions are repeated as number as users added. Is there any other way through we can do this where permissions will not repeat?

Comment: @user1273915 are you currently using code first method? I thought you need to redesign the things according to the best way (conventions used by code first).

Comment: Yes I am currently using code first method. Can you explain me how can I acheive this? Thanks.

Comment: @user1273915 could you explain your business or requirement with bit more details ?

Comment: I have a table (Permission) in my database.

ID Name
1 Page1
2 Page2
3 Page3
4 Page4
Now, when I adding user I assigning permission to that user through static checkboxes (Page1, Page2, Page3 and Page4). That’s why I created static table in a database that contains list of pages.
My User table is initially blank.
User

Id            int             NotNull
UserName      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
Password      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
FirstName     nvarchar(100)   AllowNull
LastName      nvarchar(100)   AllowNull

Comment: @user1273915 sorry Actually I am very confusion what your telling. Could you update all models and data tables(structure) with related to your question with actual requirement(clearly) of yours on above post.Don't put it on comment section.It's very difficult to read.